# iPhone: Twitter Client, how to store token, send with user request

Tags: iphone, twitter

hi developing Twitter client by using MGTwitter library and OAuth,

1) i am authenticating by Twitter server and getting token, how to store Token and send back with request r anything i have to do(i dont know what to next about Token),

2) For accessing user information like View Profile(no. of tweet, friend, retweet etc)

Can you suggest me

have a nice day

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just store it as an NSString???  If you want to save it so the user doesn't have to log in each time they use the app, just use NSUserDefaults, there are plenty of guides floating around the internet that show you how to do it.